# How to analyze spatial transcriptomic data without .h5 file?

Tags: r, seurat

I am pretty new to transcriptomics and coding in general and I am trying to analyze publicly available spatial transcriptomic data. I have analyzed it other data before, but I was provide the .h5 file and the spatial folder with the lowres image to then put into the load10x_spatial() function. However this data just gives me a features.tsv, barcodes.tsv, matrix.mtx, and a lowres.png and hihgres.png, and a few other files that I don't think are that pertinent. So my question is how do I use these files to create a seurat object?

I tried many creating an h5 file from these files but that was unsuccessful, I tried the read10x function but that didn't work. And I can't really find many other people having this problem. The ones that do, I can't really figure out what the answers people gave mean.